# ''She has been'' vs ''She was''

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

I'm doubtful about the following passive forms:

> 1. She was suggested to take off...
> 2. She has been suggested to take off...

I suggested her to take off for some days.

So, when the sentence begins with "She", which one is correct?

Comment: What is the context? In what way will this sentence be used?

Comment: I remember this sentence from B2 exam. So I had to rewrite the sentence starting with ''She''

Comment: So it was an exam question and you're trying to figure out if you missed it or not? Where there any other details to the question that might give us a context? Like a tense they specifically wanted?

Comment: Both sentences appear to be based on a construction not used in English ie _suggest someone_.

Comment: As @Cascabel said, one better way would be to say, "She was/has been advised to take off", depending on the context

Comment: I had to rewrite the sentence starting with ''she'' and adding somehow ''suggested''

Comment: Verbs like suggest, recommend, demand, etc. usually take a "that" clause. How about "She suggested that he/she take a few days off"?

Comment: @Cascabel okay, now I got it. So ''She has been suggested that she had to take off some days'' may be correct?

Comment: Or possibly "It had been suggested to her that she take time off". That retains the passive form, _suggest_, and _she_.

Comment: @Andrew and this wasn't the only mistake I found in my B2 exam. But the point was that somehow I had to rewrite the sentence starting with 'she', adding ''suggested'' in a black space and then it was already written ''to take off etc etc.'' I'm quite sure that the main sentence was ''I suggested to her to take off for some days''

Comment: @marticopi  I changed my comment to an answer, which is hopefully more illuminating why the question is malformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire question is simply wrong. "She" is not the object of "suggested" -- rather it's the entire phrase "she take time off".   In this context, *suggest* doesn't take a person as an object.  I can suggest a course of action *to* someone, but I don't *suggest* the person directly.

A different context where this does work is if I am suggesting a person for something like a job:

> I suggested them as potential replacements for the ministers who recently resigned.

In this case I can invert and use the passive voice:

> They were suggested (by me) as potential replacements ...

But that's not the case with your example.  Here you simply *can't* start the sentence with "she" and use "suggest" as a passive. It doesn't make sense.  Instead you have to replace it with another verb which *does* take a person as the object, like *advise*, or *order*.

Comment: Okay :) Thank you so much, now I got it. But the point is that the sentence was as I wrote. Maybe the next time I'll call my teacher to say that like this it's impossible. Thanks!

Comment: @marticopi if it's a test, you gotta do what you gotta do and argue with the teacher after you get your grade.  It's the nature of the system.  But now you know better  :)

Answer (score 0):

It's all the fault of the passive voice. The form *She has been suggested* is the worst of the choices you offer.

Why does the sentence have to start with 'She'? Says who? What did the poor thing do at the time of all this suggestion? Sounds like she did very little. Maybe she understood that she needed rest. Okay then, "She heard the suggestion that she take off for some days."

Comment: Yes, bad passive voice-bad. I guess it was being _aggresive_;-)

Comment: As I said, it was written in my B2 exam. I didn't want to start with ''she'' but I had to :) So I only wanted to know if it's possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, you really want to use the passive voice, you would need a different verb because "suggest" cannot be used this way. In this particular context, you would probably want something like "advised":

active voice:

> I advised her to take off for a few days.
>
> I have advised her to take off for a few days.

becomes, in the passive voice:

> She was advised to take off for a few days.
>
> She has been advised to take off for a few days.

If you simply describing a past incident, you would use the simple past tense:

*She was advised to take off for a few days.*

If you are discussing an event that began in the past but has continued to the present, you would use the present perfect tense:

*She has been advised to take off for a few days.*

The implication of this last sentence, using the present perfect, is that she was advised to take off (this was done in the past) and I am still waiting (at this moment in the present) to see whether she will follow the advice.